# HSL colour logic for JS and canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html5-canvas, web-audio-api

I am using [spectrogram](https://github.com/borismus/spectrogram) and its working fine within my ctx.

As over all color i am using css `filter: hue-rotate(160);`

Can someone please explain me how he is suggesting colours for the waveform or the energy plot within the spectrogram and how the background is decided ?

I mean the background colour and the colour of the energy plot ?

I tried random changing of values but it seems to break the spectrogram plot.
Clearly I am not understanding how the colours are derived ? All I am able to do is use a universal filter for the canvas.

It would be great if I can control the background color and energy plot colour.

[JS line on Git](https://github.com/borismus/spectrogram/blob/master/g-spectrogram.js#L230)

```
getFullColor(value) {
    var fromH = 62;
    var toH = 0;
    var percent = value / 255;
    var delta = percent * (toH - fromH);
    var hue = fromH + delta;
    return 'hsl(H, 100%, 50%)'.replace(/H/g, hue);
  }
```

Thank you
:)

EDIT: added relevant colour section from the js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HSL color model uses three components to compose a color - Hue, Saturation and Lightness. In the code saturation is hard-coded to 100%, which means that the color will be most saturated; as you decrease the value it will transition more to grayscale. The lightness regulates the value of grayscale (from black to white),  50% sets is right in the middle between full black and full white. Hue represents the "color" itself i.e. red, blue, purple, etc. By applying different saturation and lightness to a color, we can create different versions of it (dark red, light red, etc).

HSL model can be visualized as a cylinder, where lightness maps to it's height, saturation maps to radius and the colors (or hue) are distributed around the circle from 0 to 360 degrees.

[image: HSL cylinder]

To pick a color you need a value from 0 to 360. The order of the colors is well defined. At 0 degrees is pure red, as you increase the value and go around the circle you get to orange, yellow, green and so on. At 360 degrees you come back to red.

[image]

Finally, getting back to the code, a hue is the only thing being calculated, and it will define the final color. The library author defined two variables `fromH = 62` and `toH = 0`, which basically tells what sector of the hue circle will be a source of the final color.

[image]

Then library author converts the frequency value (0-255) to a hue value between 0 and 62. Lower frequency value will result to hue value close to 62 degrees (yellow-orange color), higher frequency value will be closer to hue value of 0 (closer to the pure red).

```
if (value == 0)   hue = 62;
if (value == 100) hue = 37.6;
if (value == 255) hue = 0;
```

If you want to change the color (hue) of the plot, you should adjust the variables `fromH` and `toH` to pick a sector of the circle with the color range you want.

<sup>Credit to https://science.wikia.org/ru/wiki/HSL_%D0%B8_HSV_(%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8) for the image.</sup>

---

**Update**:

The original function can be modified to allow changing the ranges for saturation and lightness as well. The background you are aiming for `#2a2c2d` in HSL is `hls(200°, 3%, 17%)`. If you want to keep the color as a basis, you could play around with saturation and lightness ranges.

```
getFullColor: function(value) {
  var fromH = 200;
  var toH = 200;

  var fromS = 10;
  var toS = 50;

  var fromL = 20;
  var toL = 50;

  var percent = value / 255;

  var hue = fromH + percent * (toH - fromH);
  var saturation = fromS + percent * (toS - fromS);
  var lightness = fromL + percent * (toL - fromL);

  return 'hsl(H, S%, L%)'
    .replace(/H/, hue)
    .replace(/S/, saturation)
    .replace(/L/, lightness);
}
```

You can just google your color "#2a2c2d", you will see a google search color picker. It displays an HSL value as well. By moving the color selector you can find the color you want for the max value and see it's HLS value.

[image]

Basically "#2a2c2d" is you background color and it is composed from `fromXXX` variables. What is left is to find the brightest color for max frequency value, it's components should be set to `toXXX` variables. The function will give you a smooth transition between two colors.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I played with the values. Still I am not understanding as the definition is only for the lines ie the freq he defines the line colours for the canvas. Somehow the background colour or canvas fill color is also set. How do i get control over the canvas fill colour and let the lines colors be from the Freq variables .. <img src="https://i.imgur.com/mxUUnZi.png">

Comment: @Akash have you changed only the `fromH` and `toH`, or you changed something else? What colors do you want to have in the end? From what I can see in the code of the library there is no any background color, background seems to be derived from `fromH` mostly.

Comment: Yes. I changed the `fromH = 188` and `toH =0`. In the end I would like the background to be `#2a2c2d`. changing fromH and toH seems to change the waveform color as well as background colour. I also tried different values and permutation with filters `filter: brightness(1.13) contrast(3) hue-rotate(193deg) saturate(2.96)`

Comment: @Akash I've added an update to my answer, please check it out. Basically you can change the function to be able to transition between background color and brightest color using all of the HSL components. What is needed from you is to set background color HSL components to `fromXXX` variables and max freq value color to `toXXX` variables.